# Get property of not related component in Angular

Tags: angular

How can I get a property of another component if they are not related. I know about shareable services, is there any other way?

Comment: You can pass data from a component to another if the second component is the child of the first one. More info here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: can you share some of the code so we can know your components structure ? 

Answer (score 1):

You can use Observables in RxJs

```
//message.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MessageService {

  private messageCommand = new Subject<string>();
  messageCommand$ = this.messageCommand.asObservable();

  invokeMessage(msg: string) {
    this.messageCommand.next(msg);
  }
}

//component-one.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-one',
  templateUrl: './component-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-one.component.css']
})
export class ComponentOneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  yourActionMethod() {
    this.messageService.invokeMessage('This is from component one');
  }
}

//component-two.ts

import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-two',
  templateUrl: './component-two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-two.component.css']
})
export class ComponentTwoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  messageSubscription: Subscription;
  message: string;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToMessageEvents();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.messageSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  subscribeToMessageEvents() {
    this.messageSubscription = this.messageService.messageCommand$.subscribe(
      (msg: string) => {
        this.message = msg;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Here I have used a service class containing an observable of type string.

Then from component-one, a message is published using the invokeMessage method in our message service.

The component which needs to receive the message, in our case component-two should subscribe to the messsageCommand$ in the message service.

> Always make sure to unsubscribe the subscription when destroying the component.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Aspram you should create an output or a shared service in order to do this.

I will show you

> with @output()

#### header.component.ts

```
export class Header implements OnInit {

  @Output() onheaderInit: EventEmitter<Header> = new EventEmitter<Header>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onheaderInit.emit(this);
  }
}
```

> Then you can consume this

```
<header (onheaderInit)="getTheClass($event)">
```

> The second method use Subject

#### sharedService.ts

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

  public onheaderInit: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor() { }

}
```

#### header.component.ts

```
export class Header implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._sharedService.onheaderInit.next(this);
  }
}
```

> Then you can consume this

```
this._sharedService.onheaderInit.subscribe( res => {
  console.log(res)
});
```